# How to add number value in a checkedListBox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a project and I want to add values to my checkedListBox.In my checkedlistbox items I have 3 items which are shoes,pants and shirt.I want to know how do i add number values to them and for example have that value * 4 and send the result directly to a textbox.[image]

Comment: There is literally many ways to solve this based on the way the project is laid out.  If it's MVC, MVVM, or just code behind it changes the way this can be answered.  Hopefully the values in the CheckedListBox are objects with individual properties and if so you just get the one checked and do the work on that value. However; I have a feeling this is a very beginner application and in that case it would require more of a lesson than a direct answer to help.  I  mean no offense in that and encourage you to keep reading and learning more about all of it.

Answer (score 0):

this might not the shortest answer.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Shoes - $250.23");
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Pants - $347.51");
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add("shirt - $150.94");

        foreach (object j in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            string x = j as string;
            double xx = Convert.ToDouble(x.Substring(x.IndexOf("$")+1))*4;
            MessageBox.Show(xx.ToString());
        }
    }
```